# Is it possible to use macro conditions with template arguments in C++?

Tags: c++, templates

Something like:

```
template<bool HOLD_MANUFACTURER>
class Computer {
     int memory;
     int storage;
 #if HOLD_MANUFACTURER
     char *manufacturer;
 #endif
};
```

I need this to create two variations of the almost-same class, when one variation is a lighter one for performance reasons. I don't want to use a separate class that will wrap the lighter one.

If yes, is it possible to any type (not just bool from the sample code above)? Maybe primitive types only? What about enums?

This code don't work for me, but I hope that I've just missed some little thing.

Comment: To the good answers here I'll add that the reason you cannot do this is because the preprocessor kicks in before the compiler.

Comment: aren't the template arguments a preprocessor thing?

Comment: @Reflection No, preprocessor is at pre-compilation, template arguments are at compile-time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not possible, but you can use template specialization and inheritance:

```
template <bool HoldManufacturer>
class ComputerAdditions
{};

template <>
class ComputerAdditions<true>
{
protected:
    char *manufacturer;

public:
    // Methods using this additional member
};

template <bool HoldManufacturer = false>
class Computer
    : public ComputerAdditions<HoldManufacturer>
{
    int memory;
    int storage;

public:
    // Methods of Computer
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can creatively use the empty base optimization in a policy approach to achieve almost what you want:

```
struct NO_MANUFACTURER {};
struct HOLD_MANUFACTURER { char *manufacturer; };

template <typename ManufacturerPolicy>
class Computer : public ManufacturerPolicy
{
     int memory;
     int storage;
}
```

Then instantiate as `Computer<HOLD_MANUFACTURER> computer_with_manufacturer;`

Comment: What if I want to put a piece of code to operate inside the macro condition from the example above? Operations instead of declaration. Is there a better way than using a class that will inherit from interface that will include a function for that specific operations?

Comment: @Reflection That really depends on what precisely you want to do (it sounds almost like you need a new, more specific question, with exact particulars you need). As stated here a parent class from which you can inherit extra members and operations is perfectly reasonable.